Why should Daniel 9 be understood as Messianic?
The word meshiach just means anointed one. So what indication is there that Daniel 9 is about the Messiah? Further reading would be appreciated, thanks!

The OP asks for further reading, so that shall be the focus.
A very useful book on Daniel 9:24-27 is "Daniel's Seventy Weeks" by Pastor Derek Walker of Oxford Baptist Church.  (Pastor Walker is a dispensationalist, I am amill, so we differ a bit, but I still agree with his overall interpretation.) (Pastor Walker does not give the meaning of the 7 and 62 weeks: in my opinion, the 62 weeks are approx 434 years of the Prophetic Silence from the completion of the OT (with the book of Nehemiah) to the beginning of the ministry of John the Baptist, Luke 3:1.)
To see how reasonable (obvious?) Pastor Walker's explanation is you might want to buy "From Abraham to Paul - a Biblical Chronology" by Andrew Steinmann.
And to see how Steinmann's book is in harmony with history you need "Babylonian Chronology - 626 bc to AD 75" by Richard A. Parker and Waldo Dubberstein.
Other great books on Daniel are "Daniel the Prophet" by E. B. Pusey, 1868; "Daniel" by Edward Young. Young helps to understand the precise meaning of the Hebrew and Aramaic. Also "A Survey of Old Testament Introduction" by Gleason Archer. Oh, and "Dare to Stand Alone" by Stuart Olyott, for sermon preparation.
The Jews in the New Testament era were expecting "the Messiah, the Son of the Living God".  There are only two passages from which this expectation could arise, Psalm 2 and Daniel 9:24-27, nowhere else.
So Peter declared "You are The Christ [The Messiah], the Son of the Living God", Matthew 16:16.
And in Mark 14:60-65 the High Priest asks Jesus "Are you the Christ [the Messiah], the Son of the Blessed?" Jesus replied "I am. And [quoting from Daniel 7:13] you shall see the Son of man sitting on the right hand of power and coming in the clouds of heaven".
These statements from the NT can only be understood if Daniel 9:24-27 and Psalm 2 are referring to a single Anointed One, THE Anointed One. They cannot just be talking about "an anointed one".
Finally, Daniel 9:26 tells us the "Messiah shall be cut off, but not for himself".  This fits perfectly with Isaiah's prophecy of chapter 53, "for the transgression of my people was he stricken", v8, and
"the punishment that brought us peace was upon him".

The Jews in the New Testament era were expecting "the Messiah, the Son of the Living God" - where do you derive that from?

@AviAvraham - Actually this is a good question in its own right.  If you want to ask it, feel free.  If you don't, are you OK if I ask it?

Please go ahead, I am interested to see

@AviAvraham - OK, thanks.

@AviAvraham - OK, I've asked a question.  It is quite clear from the New Testament there was an expectation (John 4:25, Luke 2:26, and several other passages), but it would be good to get a broader picture from non-NT sources.

@AviAvraham - these other sources could include the way the Hebrew is translated into the Greek in the Septuagint, the Targums, the Mishnah, the Talmud, Rabbinic comments on the Tanakh from the era, the writings of Josephus and Philo.
